# Is Firebase a valid replacement for MQTT?

Tags: mqtt

I wonder if the realtime techology of Firebase (Either Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database) is a valid workaround for MQTT, for avoiding the broker link. We must bear in mind that the system could be used in a ESP8266 or similar, so it should be compatible as well.

Comment: why do you want to avoid the MQTT broker?

Comment: @jsotola because it would simplify a lot the scalability process, thinking about an industrial manufacturing scale. With the broker, each device must have his own ¿Database?